# Publish FormBuilder to Edit Contact

Tags: wordpress, contacts, profile, formbuilder, individual

In my **WordPress installation** I am working with a **form** to **edit** a **profile** because we need contacts to be able to fill in information from their own custom fields. I have also enabled the two boxes for "Upgrade" and "Accept ID from URL",
[image]

however when I open the link with ID contact in another browser **I DO NOT SEE THE PROFILE AND THE FIELDS**. Am I doing something wrong?

https://www.redmaternoinfantil.org.mx/civicrm/prueba/#?individual=1250

> (I can only see it if I'm logged in)

[image]

**This is the configuration of the form:**

1. Permission: **CiviCRM: Edit Profile**
2. Accessible on front-end of website: **Enable**

   [image]
3. Security: **Open Access**
4. Allowed Actions: **Update**
5. Autofill: Neither

   [image]

Comment: I have the same question. @suri-gangs-hallen, have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am starting to test Form Builder, making my first steps, and faced the same issue.
My understanding is that you need your form to be accessible by users that are not loggued in, right ?
What I found is that the permission on the form should be :
"Generic / allow all users (including anonymous)"
Did you come to the same conclusion?

[image]